# Речевые ошибки.

Tags: грамотная-речь

Недавно писал сочинение. Скажите, где в предложении речевая ошибка и почему?

> "Ася была готова пойти  на молитву",на трудный подвиг

Вот цитата из текста:

> "Пойти куда-нибудь далеко, на молитву,
> на трудный подвиг."

Пойти на молитву - это тоже очень серьёзный шаг, но не подвиг. Это значит отказаться от беспечной жизни. А подвиг - это гораздо шире, т.е. оставить неизгладимый след в жизни, совершить какое-то действие. Например, спасти кого-то, рискуя своей жизнью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ася была готова пойти на трудный
> подвиг, на молитву.

Видимо, учительница не обратила внимание, что "трудный подвиг" - это из текста, сам автор допустил смысловую избыточность, но у него не ошибка, а средство изобразительности, он подчеркнул трудность подвига или в значении "подвиг труда", "трудовой подвиг".  Но вообще-то подвиг уже говорит о трудности, Вы правильно понимаете смысл, это самоотверженный поступок, т.е. во имя людей, он всегда связан  с большими трудностями, часто с риском для жизни. Поэтому "трудный подвиг" - речевая ошибка. Если бы Вы взяли в кавычки, ошибки бы не было. А в том виде, что у Вас, ещё недочёт в грамматике, в построении предложения. Ася была готова пойти на трудный подвиг, на молитву. - воспринимается как уточнение - от широкого к узкому смыслу, а здесь уточнения нет, лучше оставить порядок однородных членов, как у автора "...куда-нибудь далеко, на молитву, на трудный подвиг" - здесь градация, усиление признака: на молитву и даже на "трудный подвиг" (подвиг труда).

Comment: Думаю, что здесь "подвиг" употреблен в религиозном смысле, а не "подвиг труда".

Comment: Ну да, в религиозном, только всё равно труда - старинное церковное значение: подвиг-`выполнение строгих обязательств и обрядностей, связанных с проявлениями религиозного чувства; налагаемое монашеским званием аскетическое самоусовершенствование'.Действительно трудное дело, потому и подвиг трудный, но здесь ещё и церковное значение слова "трудный"- в трудах над собой, в испытаниях и аскетизме, которые связаны и с физическим трудом тоже. Это ведь слова тургеневской Аси, когда она увидела богомольцев.Это был возвышенный порыв, когда она была готова пойти с ними, и даже в монахи-отшельники.

Comment: А жизнь отщельника-тяжкий труд